# PHP 5.4 undefined index: argv

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I've already checked to see if `register_argc_argv` is on in my `php.ini` file (it is) and I'm using `PHP-CLI`.

This is the error message I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message
>   'Undefined index: argv' in
>   phar:///var/www/html/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php:57\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   phar:///var/www/html/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php(57):
>   Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(8, 'Undefined index...',
>   'phar:///var/www...', 57, Array)\n#1
>   phar:///var/www/html/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(111):
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->__construct()\n#2
>   phar:///var/www/html/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php(83):
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(NULL,
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))\n#3
>   phar:///var/www/html/composer.phar/bin/composer(43):
>   Composer\Console\Application->run()\n#4
>   /var/www/html/composer.phar(15): require('phar:///var/www...')\n#5
>   /var/www/html/db.php(13): require_once('/var/www/html/c...')\n#6
>   {main}\n  thrown in
>   phar:///var/www/html/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php
>   on line 57

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is what was causing the error:

```
foreach (scandir(dirname(__FILE__)) as $filename) {
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $filename;
    if (is_file($path)) {
        require_once $path;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain the error at all! Perhaps it makes sense to *you*, but it won't help anyone else.